# Could I have achieved my goal by phrasing this answer differently?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

In a [recent answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/17592/1467) on Aviation.SE I originally wrote:

> Why is part from B777 being analysed by Airbus?
>   Because it is not.

The answer immediately attracted some comments from the native English speakers of the community focusing on the incorrect structure of the sentence.

As I tried to explain later in the corresponding chat

> I made the deliberate decision to write not in the best grammatical form to stress the point that the assumption behind the question is wrong. I'm not sure wether I achieve my goal, but my intent was the above.

I basically went for a double why-because question-answer sequence to build a rithm and to break it with the incorrect sentence structure to draw the reader attention on the point.

In the end, also given the technical predisposition of the SE community, I accepted the objections that were raised against my choice and I have not reverted the final edit, but I am still wondering: could have I achieved my intent? Would there have been better alternatives?

Comment: "Why is part from B777" should be "Why is a part from a B777"

Comment: @chaslyfromUK if you look at the answer linked you'll see that that was part of the original question that I simply quoted verbatim (and that got corrected subsequently)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is a part from a B777 being analysed by Airbus? Because it is not.

The word "because" is used to introduce a ***reason***.

"it is not" does not provide a reason for the part being analysed.

Instead I suggest,

"Why is a part from a B777 being analysed by Airbus? It isn't!"

Comment: I know that, and as said I deliberatly did it to create "dissonance" (stealing a music terminology). I'm asking wether it was appropriate and/or if better alternatives exist.

Comment: There is a dissonance but it doesn't work in English. The nearest I can suggest is, "...by Airbus? It isn't!"

Comment: could you consider adding the comment explanation into the answer to complete it?

Comment: @Federico - Certainly, no problem.